# when i run an express router in terminal is not showing any result or error, Node.js and MogoDB

Tags: node.js, express, router

when i run my file in terminal (node reviews.route.js) is not showing any errors or results. im new to backend Node.js and MongoDB. i have downlod all of this models in package.json, "cors":"^2.8.5","dotenv":"^16.0.3","express":"^4.18.2","router":"^1.3.7".
thanks..

server.js file:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from cors;
import reviews from '/api/reviews.route.js';
//creating web server
const app=express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/v1/reviews', reviews);
app.use('*', (req,res)=>res.status(404).json({error:"Not found"}));

export default app;
```

reviews.route.js file:

```
import express from 'express';
const router=express.Router();

router.route("/").get((req,res)=>res.send("Hello world"));

export default router;
```

there is no result or an erro showing when i run the file and nothing appear on browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't create the server, you have to include in your server.js the code

```
    app.listen( 3000, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port 3000`);
});
```

You can change the port to another (If it is a hosting then it would be `process.env.PORT`)

Also you dont have to `export default app`.
Then run in the terminal "node server.js"

In your browser write localhost:3000

i hope have helped you

Comment: tanks, i just added    app.listen( 3000, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port 3000`);
}); and its works